# Transmission or engine Problem?

Tags: honda, civic, shifting

2012 Honda Civic stutters when shifting from 1st to 2nd gear(automatic trans.) and sometimes from 2nd to 3rd. If I drive it in D3 it doesn't do this. Had the sparks, ignition coils, and trans. fluid changed per dealer with no effect. Is this the transmission or the engine?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you shifting your automatic transmission manually? Try to just put it in OD (regular old "D" just past "N") and let the transmission drive itself and see if this changes anything.

Comment: Regular old D is where this all started. The chattering/shuddering only occurs when the car is in D. I accidently put it in D3 and realized there was no shuddering until I put it back into Drive. and no, other than putting it in D3 I'm not shifting manually

Answer (score 1):

There are known problems with the shift control solenoids on the Honda Civic that cause problems between first and second. The recommendation is to replace the solenoid and flush/fill the transmission fluid.

Comment: It would be helpful to give some guidance about where the shift control solenoids are located and whether that is something a back yard mech can do or does it require a shop professional.

Answer (score 0):

What you've stated in the comments would lead me to the transmission having issues. The transmission could be shuddering trying to go into torque converter lockup. You'll most likely need to take it to a transmission shop and have them look at it.

Comment: What is "torque converter lockup"? I need to take my car back to the dealer as I have an extended warranty that covers the transmission. The shudder doesn't happen every time I accelerate from a stop or a slowdown but it appears more frequently if driven for longer periods, and again it doesn't happen at all if I drive in D3.